# How can I connect to a remotely SQL database using IP via WPF in App.config file?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, string

Trying to connect in a remote database via IP using WPF, I place the following code in the App.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="Data Source=tcp:XXX.XXX.X.XX,1433; User Id=ex****;Password=ex*******; Initial Catalog=database_name;" name="ConString"/>
  </connectionStrings>  
</configuration>
```

The above throws me a message that says "An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll"

I placed "tcp" because is what I met **googling** for connecting to a remotely database over IP(my case). Do I have other "options" instead of that?

Notice that I am connecting over vpn and also that I have full access using SQL Management Studio.

Expanding the error message gives me the bellow description:
[image: Error message]

As I said I have full access in the remotely database via SQL Management Studio, so I suppose that the problem has to do with the syntax of the connectionstring code in App.config file.

Except all, in the Catalog I am placing the **name** of the database right?

Comment: Do you have 
    <configSections>
        <!-- connectionstrings go in here  -->
    </configSections>

Comment: @Master117 Can you explain that please? The above is my full code in the App.config file.

Comment: Could you show related code? And we need to know which line is problem. By the way, will this WPF be deployed to users' computers? Be careful with your password. You're delivering the password on paper together.

Comment: @KayLee This is my full code, I created a blank WPF app and I am trying from the beginning to be connected in a remotely database. All I have is an IP, a username and a password. After placing the code above, I tried to run the project, in order to see if everything is ok and then got the message  **"An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll"** I totally confused on how to be connected.

Comment: Does its show the line with the error?

Comment: @Master117 Please take a look at the image in the answer.

Comment: try User ID instead of User Id, not sure if thats the problem.

Comment: Did you try creating the connectionstring in your code instead of app.config?

Comment: @Master117 It is not but thank you

Comment: Are you sure the error is there? select `View Detail..` in the exception window and analize that extra info. Also, don't use an answer to expand your question, use the edit link in your question and update what you need there.

Comment: Ok..try `connectionString` with a capital `S`

Comment: @Pikoh thank you for the response. Please take a look at the image I just attached(either in the question and in the answer). Adding a capital  "s" the error is still there. Thank you.

Comment: Did you added it in all `connectionString` and `connectionStrings`? see the code in my answer

Comment: @Pikoh I added capital S and also capital D (User ID). The full code is included in the question. I have not something more. Thank you

Comment: Then update the code in your question so we can see how do you have it now. Anyway, in `User Id` the `d` is not capital

Comment: I recommend to start with code. Please try to 'Be basic' first. . Sorry, because I'm outside, I cannot test your case.

Comment: Once again, the `S`must be capital, also in `<connectionStrings>`. See my code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML is case-sensitive. The `S` in `string` must be capital:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="Data Source=tcp:XXX.XXX.X.XX,1433; User Id=ex****;Password=ex*******; Initial Catalog=database_name;" name="ConString"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try forcing the usage of TCP/IP instead of named pipes for your connection with: `Network Library=DBMSSOCN;` after the `Data Source` element.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion but nothing. I placed "tcp" because is what I met googling for connecting to a remotely database over IP. Do I have other options instead of that?

Comment: You can find the list of avalable protocols [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/define-sql-server-network-protocol/). But if that didn't help I doubt that other options of that parameter will work for you.